# Navigation bar disappears faster than view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have 2 view controllers, View controller 1 doesn't have navigation bar but view controller 2 has navigation bar. When popping from view controller 2 to view controller 1 the navigation bar disappears faster than the view. What could be a solution to this. Please help.

Comment: Do you use `UINavigationController` push/pop?

Comment: yes. [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES]; and [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Then use `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]`